# Google spreadsheets custom function code not working: =RootDomain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I am trying to program a Google spreadsheets custom function. It receives a range and spits out the clean rootdomain. I just ran into an "too many executions" - I have to run this on my whole sheet. So I added a range.

Now the feedback is "internal error function" ....

Help appreciated .... this must be possible!

```
/**
 * Generates clean root domains
 *
 * @param {input} input The value to change to a root domain.
 * @return The clean root domain.
 * @RootDomain
 */
function RootDomain(input) {
  if (input == null) return '';
  if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(RootDomain); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    if (input = '') return '';
    regex = new RegExp(/((www)\.)?.*(\w+)\.([\w\.]{2,6})/);
    return regex.exec(input)[0].replace(/^http(s)?:\/\//i, "").replace(/^www\./i, "").replace(/\/.*$/, "");
  }
}
```

Comment: Change **if (input = '') return '';** to **if (input === '') return '';** . You are turning **input** to null when you use only one '=' sign

Comment: THX!! Problem is that with three === it compares for string, but what happens if INPUT is null (when no input is selected or cell is empty)

Comment: No, with === it will check if input is empty or not. What you are doing is making input '' which you don't want.

Comment: Also it should be **var regex = new RegExp(/((www)\.)?.*(\w+)\.([\w\.]{2,6})/);**

Comment: Also **return input.map(RootDomain)** does not do anything as you have not defined the input for recurse.

Comment: All updated. Still results in error when debugging "TypeError: Cannot read property "map" from undefined. (line 10, file "RootDomain""

Comment: Hmmm what should that be then? I took that code advise from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: Never mind, that part is correct. I will paste my code as an answer, see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
function RootDomain(input) {
  if (input == null || input === '') { 
  return '';
  } else if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
  return input.map(RootDomain); // Recurse over array if so.
  }
    var regex = new RegExp(/((www)\.)?.*(\w+)\.([\w\.]{2,6})/);
    return regex.exec(input)[0].replace(/^http(s)?:\/\//i, "").replace(/^www\./i, "").replace(/\/.*$/, "");
  }
```

Comment: Works for 1 cell. Now did: =rootdomain(D2:D10000) because otherwise we run into a calculation issue "Too many calculations" or something. The error now is #REF

Comment: Why are you even doing it over 100000 rows?